# Closing activity from another activity by a click

Tags: android

I am using an activity as a pop-up window which appears on a click event. The pop-up activity overlays on another activity (say Activity_2) which has a button at its bottom. I want to close the popup activity on click of the button at Activity_2.

I don't want pop-up to be closed on touch outside. The button does not responds to the click when I am doing it now.

Here is my code

**Popup Activity**

```
public class Pop extends AppCompatActivity {

    Activity popup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop);
    popup=this;

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*0.9),(int)(height*0.6) );

}

}
```

**Activity_2**

```
cont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        popup.finish();
        }
    });
```

**Style**

```
<style name="AppTheme.customtheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a `DialogFragement` or `Dialog` with custom view?!

Comment: What @AtefHares says. You can capture when someone is dismissing the dialog by clicking outside and override the close behavior